# This code is to get the data from inv sheet column N to sheet rep column B Run-Time Error "1004" Method 'Range of object_'worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

**This code is to get the data from inv sheet column N to sheet rep column B**

**fw2 = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1**

```
Inv.Range("B9:N500").ClearContents
Inv.Range("B8:N" & 8 + fw2).Cells.Value = ListBox1.List

with Rep
   .Range(.Cells(lastrow, "J"), .Cells(lastrow + fw2 - 1, "S")) = Inv.Range("B9:K" & 8 + 
     fw2).Value 'all products


      'Here is the one I want to modify 
       Run-Time Error "1004"
        Method 'Range of object_'worksheet' failed

    .Range(.Cells(lastrow, "B")) = Inv.Range("N9:N" & 8 + fw2).Value  
End With
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Please see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: 'Here is the line I want to modify 
       Run-Time Error "1004"
        Method 'Range of object_'worksheet' failed

    .Range(.Cells(lastrow, "B")) = Inv.Range("N9:N" & 8 + fw2).Value

Comment: @Scott Craner  'Here is the line need to modify 
       Run-Time Error "1004"
        Method 'Range of object_'worksheet' failed

    .Range(.Cells(lastrow, "B")) = Inv.Range("N9:N" & 8 + fw2).Value

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(lastrow, "B"))` should just be: `.Cells(lastrow, "B")`

Comment: I did this but giving me the same error    Cells(lastrow, "B") = Inv.Range("N9:N" & 8 + fw2).Value

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(lastrow, "B"), .Cells(lastrow + fw2 - 1, "B")).Value = Inv.Range("N9:N" & 8 + fw2).Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is generated when in your expression the left side is one cell, but the right side's range consists of more than one cell.
Replace the line

```
    .Range(.Cells(lastrow, "B")) = Inv.Range("N9:N" & 8 + fw2).Value
```

to

```
    .Range(.Cells(lastrow, "B") , .Cells(lastrow + fw2, "B")) = Inv.Range("N9:N" & 8 + fw2).Value
```